# no returning data from database php

Tags: php

What's wrong with this code?

```
  $query = "select * from user where email= '$email'";

if( mysql_num_rows( $query )==0 ){
    echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';

  }else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
        $id=$row['id'];
        echo"yolo";
```

}

I have the email in my db `but it returns

```
 No rows returned
```

Why?

Comment: You never called `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Because query must be __executed__

Comment: Can't you find a tutorial that shows the basics of how to use mysql from PHP?

Comment: please stop using `mysql_*`(deprecated from php5.5 onward and removed from php 7). use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the query. The argument to `mysql_num_rows()` and `mysql_fetch_assoc()` must be a result returned from `mysql_query()`.

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) ==0 ){
    echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';

} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
        $id=$row['id'];
        echo"yolo";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**

This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0,`enter code here` and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information.

Using msqli

```
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

     if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     } 

     $sql = "select * from user where email= '$email'";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Email: ". $row["email"] . "<br>";
          }
     } else {
          echo "0 results";
     }
```

**To know More about mysqli**

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Where are the links?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $query = "select * from user where email= '$email'";
  $query = mysql_query($query);
 if( mysql_num_rows( $query )==0 ){
 echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';

 }else{
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
    $id=$row['id'];
    echo"yolo";

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write like this:
$query = mysql_query("select * from user where email= '$email'");

And also Read:
[The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)